# Cannonical Openstack Licensing question

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot

I was under the impression that 10 node test license was "Free". I am seeing "Outage in X days" in my Monitor your region area.

Whats even more interesting is that each day counts down 3-4 days.

Anyone have an idea or some more information on their "FREE" licensing model?

Look here: http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/plans-and-pricing

"Upto 10 Machines: FREE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Outage" is referring to the days left until Landscape thinks RAM or CPU is exhausted (which is likely invalid given a small sample size).  If you want to see license information, click on `View Licenses` under the main account page, titled `Standalone` along the top of the page.

Hope that helps you.